# Windows 7 seems to mess up ext4 group descriptors

Tags: linux, windows, ext4, fsck

I recently installed Linux Mint Debian Edition - it was installed into a logical partition (formatted to ext4) under a 40 GB extended partition that was previously used as a backup/recovery disk in Windows 7.
It works quite well - the only problem is when I boot to Windows, then next time, Linux won't boot. I then need to use a recovery distro and run fsck.ext4 which detects some problems with group descriptors, fixes them and it's all good again.
My feeling is that Windows tries to mount (and fix / defrag / whatever) that partition which messes it up - I suspect that, because 1) it only happens after I boot to Windows, 2) Windows still displays the old recovery/backup disk D: (although you cannot access it and it doesn't show a free/total space etc.).
Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, it could possibly be the listed partition type.

Check the disk with your favorite partition table editor (fdisk, cfdisk, parted, whatever), and check to see if your linux partitions are listed as Windows ones or if they are correctly listed as Linux.  If they are listed wrong, you should safely be able to change this, and it could stop Windows from harassing you.